# How would you sort txt file to find the average

Tags: python, sorting, text, average

Hello fellow coders/codets, I have been trying to find a solution to finding the average of the contents inside a txt file and write them to the output program. so far I have got the following code to trying to find the average:>>>

```
elif viewclass==('class a ave'):
    list_of_numbers = []

with open('class a.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
      if line.strip(): # this skips blank lines
          list_of_numbers.append(int(line.strip()))

print ('Total '),len(list_of_numbers)
print ('Average '),1.0*sum(list_of_numbers)/len(list_of_numbers)
```

However when the code is run i get the following output:>>>

```
Total 
Average
```

These are the two things that print out. In my file I have the following numbers to average 10 & 3 in the .txt file.

Thanks for the help :D

Comment: I don't see what this question has to do with sorting.

Comment: I thought sorting would come into it because of the numbers in the file I think i'm getting confused with putting highest to lowest. thanks :D @Rob Kennedy

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using Python 3.

```
print ('Total '),len(list_of_numbers)
print ('Average '),1.0*sum(list_of_numbers)/len(list_of_numbers)
```

The things you want to print need to all be inside the first parentheses pair.

```
print('Total ', len(list_of_numbers))
print('Average ', 1.0*sum(list_of_numbers)/len(list_of_numbers))
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin I'll try it out. :D